# ld can't find .so

Tags: ld

I installed zeromq 3.2.5 from source

```
$ wget http://download.zeromq.org/zeromq-3.2.5.tar.gz
$ tar xf zeromq-3.2.5.tar.gz
$ cd zeromq-3.2.5
$ ./configure && make -j4
$ sudo make install
```

This installs `libzmq.so.3` into `/usr/local/lib`:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate libzmq.so.3
```

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.3
> /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.3.0.0
> ```

I've confirmed that `/usr/local/lib` is in the `ld` search path:

```
$ grep /usr/local/lib /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
```

> ```
> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/libc.conf:/usr/local/lib
> ```

I've confirmed that `ld` can find the library:

```
$ ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | egrep -e zmq\|^/
```

> ```
> ...
> /usr/local/lib:
>   libzmq.so.3 -> libzmq.so.3.0.0
> ...
> ```

However, if I run `ldd` on my app, it cannot find `libzmq.so.3`

```
$ ldd test_app
```

> ```
>   ...
>   libzmq.so.3 => not found
>   ...
> ```

If I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then it works

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
$ ldd test_app
```

> ```
>   ...
>   libzmq.so.3 => /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.3 (0x00007f22418d9000)
>   ...
> ```

**Question:**

- Why can't `ld` find `libzmq.so.3` without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when it's in a standard path?
- How can I fix this without having to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

**Notes:**

The `RPATH` is set on the binary, in case that's important:

```
$ readelf -a test_app | grep RPATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [/home/steve/src/.../bin/gcc-4.9.3/debug]
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 in case that's of any use

Comment: Can you get `-rpath=/usr/local/lib` passed to the linker when compiling the test app? Via `gcc` this may require `-Wl,-rpath=...` in addition to however that home directory path is being added.

Comment: @thrig yes I could, but that doesn't seem right - more like treating the symptoms not the cause? I don't understand why if `/usr/local/lib` is in `ld.conf`, why it can't find it?

Comment: Have you run `ldconfig` without flags as `root` user to update the cache?  This is sometimes needed after a new library has been added.

Comment: @StephenHarris ah, yes, that worked! How come `ldconfig -v` could find it? If you want to put that in an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: You ran `ldconfig -v` as a non-root user if your `$` prompt is anything to go by.  This just made it scan the directories but couldn't update the cache for the runtime linker.

Comment: @StephenHarris Ah yes! Thank you! That is correct

Comment: @SteveLorimer the `-Wl,-rpath=...` method is advised by e.g. Brian Ward in "How Linux Works" to avoid `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` searches.

Comment: @thrig agreed, but `ldconfig` is configured to search in `/usr/local/lib` by default, so setting it on the rpath would be masking the real problem. (which, as it turned out, was I hadn't updated the `ldconfig` cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add new libraries to the system directories you may need to refresh the linker cache with

```
ldconfig
```

This needs to be run as `root`.

Without this command the runtime linker will have a stale idea of what libraries are available.

You similarly need to do this if you decide to add new directories to the system linker path.

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` caused the runtime linker to manually look in that directory, outside of the cache.

Comment: Warning: running `ldconfig` without options is Linux-specific.  If you'd do that on OpenBSD you'd actually clear the shared library cache.

Comment: Good warning; in this case we know it's Ubuntu but definitely worth highlighting the differences!  Thanks.